# Inflated view does not get dimmensions from xml

Tags: android, android-layout, google-maps-markers, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I'm trying to add custom view to google map [Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker):

1. I inflate a layout. **<- this is the problem**
2. Then transform it to Bitmap.
3. Generate Marker.

### So I have layout `home_marker_container.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/home_map_marker_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/home_map_marker_size"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:id="@+id/frame">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:text="5"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and I inflate it with

```
ViewGroup home_marker_container = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.home_marker_container, null, false);
```

### Then transform View to Bitmap:

So I add it to marker with [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/) via [IconGenerator](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/ui/IconGenerator.html) which basically transforms [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) to [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html):

```
iconGenerator.setContentView(home_marker_container);
iconGenerator.setContentPadding(horizontal_padding, vertical_padding, horizontal_padding, vertical_padding);
Bitmap iconBitmap = iconGenerator.makeIcon();
```

And after that I realized that inflating does not work as I expected because I give `null` to `ViewGroup root` parameter in `inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)` and thus

```
android:layout_width="@dimen/home_map_marker_size"
android:layout_height="@dimen/home_map_marker_size"
```

is not taken from xml. **Why and how to fix it?**

Comment: Have a look at http://www.nasc.fr/android/android-using-layout-as-custom-marker-on-google-map-api/

Comment: @Barbelo thanks, however the code from link doesn't seem to follow Android layout inflating rules, your hints (now deleted by SO, why?) and the link got me to answer.

Comment: I deleted it because it doesnt look to be related to the Google Maps Marker

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As there's no root, [according to docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29), root is returned from `inflate` so I set size to the root manually with:

```
View markerView;
markerView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.marker1, null);
markerView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(80, 80));;
```